# Import Excel file in flutter app for begginer

Tags: excel, flutter, import

I'm contacting you to ask for help with Flutter. I'm new to using this language and I'm having difficulty with some of the logic.

**I want to import an Excel file (placed in the assets folder) to retrieve data used in the various pages of my application**.

I've seen that there are different packages for Excel files but the excel package ([doc here](https://pub.dev/packages/excel)) seems the best. The documentation indicates the lines to use but I don't understand where to place them in the code.

**My application works globally but the problem appears when I want to import my excel file.**

In the main dart file, I've indicated the following:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:flutter_excel/excel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show ByteData, rootBundle;

Future<void> importExcelFile() {
  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/existing_excel_file.xlsx");
    var bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);
        
    for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
      print(table); //sheet Name
      print(excel.tables[table].maxCols);
      print(excel.tables[table].maxRows);
      for (var row in excel.tables[table].rows) {
        print("$row");
      }
    }
}

void main() async {
  importExcelFile();
  print('Import ok...');

  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainMenu(),
    );
  }
}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you'll need to double-check to make this work.

1. Make sure to call [`WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsFlutterBinding/ensureInitialized.html) in your `main` before calling `importExcelFile`.
2. Check your pubspec.yaml, and make sure that existing_excel_file.xlsx is listed as an asset, like so:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/file.xlsx
```